# Custom Web Outlook (OWA) authentication

Tags: authentication, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I want to create custom OWA authentication. For example, if you have default owa authentication, you will login using user's credentials, which is connected with Active Directory. In other words, you will login as Active Directory user.
Is it  possible to embed custom system of authentication which would allow not to use AD users?  We would authorize users by  external web server.

Comment: This do not make really sense, as the user must have an AD account in order to use OWA features.

Comment: Hello!
Thank you for your answer.  
But maybe there is some mix way? For instance, if my custome user is connected with an AD user, will it be possible to authenticate him in OWA?
My way will be the following: I will login as a custom user in my login page. The password and the login will be sent to my server. At my server we will know that my custom user is connected with some AD user and we will send back his AD credentinals(login and pass) to my custom form .When I get them back at my custom form, can I authenticate to OWA? The matter is, in this point I will have AD users's credentials.

Comment: You might wish to sync the remote system with ActiveDirectory, there exists some connectors. Or much better use the AD environment on the remote system for authentication.